# How can I use sed between special characters?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

If you type `id user_name` you get `uid=500(user_name)`.

How can I use `sed` to get everything between the `=` and `(` so you get `500`?

I have `sed -n ‘/=/,/(/p’`.

Comment: Please try `sed 's/^uid=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`.

Comment: How about `id -u user_name`?

Answer (score 1):

You can group the number `500` - or any integer value, for that matter - and return it with `sed 's/^uid=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`.

Answer (score 0):

@Rfroes87 provided a fine solution in a comment - `sed 's/^uid=([0-9]*).*/\1/'`

But you can do it a lot of ways that don't involve another process.

You might be able to just use something like `$UID` or $uid`already present - check your env with`set`.

You can use `read` -

```
IFS='=(' read x myUID x <<< $(id)
```

Or you could use parameter parsing in steps -

```
myUID="$(id)"
myUID="${myUID#*=}"
myUID="${myUID%%(*}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using the following: `sed 's_^uid=\(.*\)(.*$_\1_g'`